# Numpy does not run

Tags: python, numpy, python-import

I am new to numpy and recently installed numpy on macbook pro
When I try to run this code

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([1,2,3])
print(a)
```

This is what I get

```
/Users/giridhar/PycharmProjects/venv/bin/python /Users/giridhar/PycharmProjects/numpy/numpy1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/giridhar/PycharmProjects/numpy/numpy1", line 2, in <module>
    a = np.array([1,2,3])
AttributeError: module 'numpy' has no attribute 'array'
```

Process finished with exit code 1.

Comment: i guess, you must use index to access the array elements, so give like print(a[1])

Comment: Most likely you have a file called `numpy.py` in your current working directory. Please rename this file and delete any `numpy.pyc` file left over *in the current working directory only*.

Comment: I tried both the suggestions - no success.